# How to make two different date format in single column unique?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have one column in I don't understand how but there is two different format in a single column.

```
df['Date'] = [6/24/2019,6/14/2019,2019-09-06 00:00:00,6/14/2019,6/14/2019]
```

I want process it further so I want make it in a single format.

```
df['Date'] = [6/24/2019,6/14/2019,9/06/2019,6/14/2019,6/14/2019]
```

I have tried something like this

```
data['New_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%m/%d/%Y')
```

but it gave me this error

ValueError: time data 6/24/2019 doesn't match format specified

Comment: Have you tried `pd.to_datetime`?

Comment: Yes I have as I edited my question I mentioned the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with both formats and `errors='coerce'` for `NaT` if not match and replace missing values by another `Series` by [`Series.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) them, last convert to strings by [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
s1 = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')
s2 = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], format = '%m/%d/%Y', errors='coerce')

#2 possible solutions
data['new'] = s1.fillna(s2).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
data['new'] = s1.combine_first(s2).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
print (data)
                  Date         new
0            6/24/2019  06/24/2019
1            6/14/2019  06/14/2019
2  2019-09-06 00:00:00  06/09/2019
3            6/14/2019  06/14/2019
4            6/14/2019  06/14/2019
```

Answer (score 1):

Try importing the `datetime` class. This will allow you to use the `strptime` function like below:

```
format = '%d/%m/%Y'
data['New_date'] = datetime.strptime('2019-09-06 00:00:00', format)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Date'] = ['6/24/2019','6/14/2019','2019-09-06 00:00:00','6/14/2019','6/14/2019']
df['newDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
print (df)

                  Date    newDate
0            6/24/2019 2019-06-24
1            6/14/2019 2019-06-14
2  2019-09-06 00:00:00 2019-09-06
3            6/14/2019 2019-06-14
4            6/14/2019 2019-06-14
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't know this this is a simpler way to do this