# python - convert multiple string datetimes format into a specific date format

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have this column date with 6 different date strings sizes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: '2020-03-21T10:13:08',  1: '2020-03-21T17:43:03',  2: '2020-03-21T13:13:30',  3: '2020-03-21T20:43:02',  4: '3/8/20 5:31',  5: '3/8/20 5:19',  6: '3/22/20 23:45',  7: '3/22/20 23:45',  8: '2/1/2020 11:53',  9: '2/1/2020 10:53',  10: '1/31/2020 15:20',  11: '1/31/2020 10:37',  12: '2020-04-04 23:34:21',  13: '2020-04-04 23:34:21'}}, 
             index=range(0,14))
```

I need to convert all those different datetimes strings to date format. The approach I'm using is:

1. Find the first white space and extract the date
2. Change its format given a certain string length (each string length has its specific date format as you can see below in the `format` argument)
3. Do (2) in the respective rows in the dataframe `df`.

You can see this approach here:

```
df.loc[df["date"].str.find(" ") == 10, "date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[df["date"].str.find(" ") == 10, "date"].str[0:10])
df.loc[df["date"].str.find(" ") == -1, "date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[df["date"].str.find(" ") == 10, "date"].str[0:10])
df.loc[df["date"].str.find(" ") == 6, "date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[df["date"].str.find(" ") == 6, "date"].str[0:6], format="%m/%d/%y")
df.loc[df["date"].str.find(" ") == 7, "date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[df["date"].str.find(" ") == 7, "date"].str[0:7], format="%m/%d/%y")
df.loc[df["date"].str.find(" ") == 8, "date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[df["date"].str.find(" ") == 8, "date"].str[0:8], format="%m/%d/%Y")
df.loc[df["date"].str.find(" ") == 9, "date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[df["date"].str.find(" ") == 9, "date"].str[0:9], format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

I'm going perfect until step 3) where I'm trying to find a workaround to make all the format changes in the dataframe, but I can't understand why it doesn't give what it should give. Any suggestions?

By the way, it has to be scalable (I have a lot of rows per format string)

Comment: Why a `-1`? There is a reproducible example, a specific problem statement, and there is no similar question in StackOverflow. Any feedback there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me working converting all values to datetimes and then remove times with [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandaspydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) if output is datetimes or with [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) if output are python dates:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.floor('d')
#dates
#df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date
print (df)
         date
0  2020-03-21
1  2020-03-21
2  2020-03-21
3  2020-03-21
4  2020-03-08
5  2020-03-08
6  2020-03-22
7  2020-03-22
8  2020-02-01
9  2020-02-01
10 2020-01-31
11 2020-01-31
12 2020-04-04
13 2020-04-04
```

Your solution should be simplify - get first 10 letters, then split by possible space and get first values:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str[:10].str.split().str[0])
```

Comment: Pretty nice solution, I never thought of using `dt.floor`. However, how do you know if `pd.to_datetime()` doesn't mislead days for months or vice versa? (That's why I specified the formats which are different from the standard one of `pd.to_datetime()`: `%Y-%m-%d`.

Comment: @Chris - by default to_datetime working with month first like MMDDYYYY. If mixed another format it is more complicated.

Comment: Okey, got it. But then how does it read the formats YYYY-MM-DD for example? How pandas knows if it's not YYYY-DD-MM instead?

Comment: @Chris - Unfortunately not, then is necessary approach like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55866809/2901002)

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: '2020-03-21T10:13:08',  1: '2020-03-21T17:43:03',  2: '2020-03-21T13:13:30',  3: '2020-03-21T20:43:02',  4: '3/8/20 5:31',  5: '3/8/20 5:19',  6: '3/22/20 23:45',  7: '3/22/20 23:45',  8: '2/1/2020 11:53',  9: '2/1/2020 10:53',  10: '1/31/2020 15:20',  11: '1/31/2020 10:37',  12: '2020-04-04 23:34:21',  13: '2020-04-04 23:34:21'}}, 
             index=range(0,14))
df
    date
0   2020-03-21T10:13:08
1   2020-03-21T17:43:03
2   2020-03-21T13:13:30
3   2020-03-21T20:43:02
4   3/8/20 5:31
5   3/8/20 5:19
6   3/22/20 23:45
7   3/22/20 23:45
8   2/1/2020 11:53
9   2/1/2020 10:53
10  1/31/2020 15:20
11  1/31/2020 10:37
12  2020-04-04 23:34:21
13  2020-04-04 23:34:21

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df
    date
0   2020-03-21 10:13:08
1   2020-03-21 17:43:03
2   2020-03-21 13:13:30
3   2020-03-21 20:43:02
4   2020-03-08 05:31:00
5   2020-03-08 05:19:00
6   2020-03-22 23:45:00
7   2020-03-22 23:45:00
8   2020-02-01 11:53:00
9   2020-02-01 10:53:00
10  2020-01-31 15:20:00
11  2020-01-31 10:37:00
12  2020-04-04 23:34:21
13  2020-04-04 23:34:21
```