# How can I unify a column with different time formats into one single format?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date, formatting, time-series

I would like to put all the values from the column 'Date' in the same time-format (like for example: 25/11/2020).

[image]

I tried

`matches['Date'] = matches['Date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')[0])`

And got the result:

[image]

I have already seen there are different topics of this style in stackoverflow but none of them seems to work for my case. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `dayfirst=True`:

```
matches['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(matches['Date'], dayfirst=True).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: This is awesome code thanks for sharing, could you please do let me know how do I practice this much to remember these many options :) Any help/guidance will be greatly appreciated sir, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - If want specify exactly format is possible use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55866809/2901002)